# Why is my system crashing after using Spotify?

Tags: 22.10

i have just newly started using Ubuntu and i have been facing a problem since this morning. As i installed Spotify from Ubuntu software and started using it, it functions fine and plays normally. But as soon as I click anywhere else in the window, the entire system freezes. What can I do?

Comment: What version of Spotify? Is it installed as a Snap or as a native package? 

Is your machine fully updated? Are you also refreshing Snaps when you update?

Comment: First off, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Spotify? It might help. Also, ensure your system and all your drivers are up to date – those updates can sometimes resolve such problems.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2003607) with applications using Electron (Spotify, Slack, Chrome, etc).

For the good news, disabling OpenGL in thoses apps may fix the problem.

- For Spotify and Slack, you can go to **Ubuntu settings** -> **Applications** -> **Spotify**/**Slack** and uncheck **opengl: Allow access to OpenGL stack**
- For Slack, you can also disable it from the app (rapidly before it crashes !), in

  - **Preferences** -> **Advanced** -> **Other options** -> check **Disable hardware accelaration**

If it still doesn't work, we will have to wait for the fix ; A bug [fix was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1995956) in January 2023, but not yet for Ubuntu, sorry !

Comment: Thank you for this, I thought I was going crazy! I noticed Spotify and Prospect Mail started freezing my Ubuntu lately and had to stop using them. It makes sense that's it's a bug with Electron.

Comment: @NadirSidi I found a workaround ! I updated the answer accordingly, I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you @EliseEtc

Comment: Dear Ninjas, do we have a `Mint Linux` equivalent to this solution?